# How to create Settings option for a website

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, web, settings

How to create a settings option for a website that allows users to change the background color, language, dark mode and light mode?

I want Settings Option Which is similar to Qwant Homepage settings

Comment: You should give more context about your need and start by doing some research first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide a code, remember that this forum seeks to solve problems.

I've made a quick example of how you can make a theme system.

You can use two buttons and `useState` to toggle this. Also, you can use cookies to storage the actual theme of the user.

This is an example component:

First, install

```
npm install js-cookie
```

Then, create a component file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Toggler = () => {

  const toggleTheme = (themeType) => {
    Cookies.set('theme', themeType);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => toggleTheme('light')}>Light Theme</button>
      <button onClick={() => toggleTheme('dark')}>Dark Theme</button>
      <p>Current theme is {theme}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Toggler;
```

Then you can call Toggler from other components. Also you can get the mode with `Cookies.get('theme')`

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

const [theme, setTheme] = useState(Cookies.get('theme') || 'light');
```

Once you have the theme, you can use this as conditional for your styles or html code.